# Incremental/Instant/Hot Deploy with NetBeans and *remote* Glassfish

Tags: maven, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

NetBeans 7.3.1 has the nice ability of doing an incremental deploy of e.g. JSF pages to a Glassfish server which makes changes visible almost immediately.

This features does not seem to work for a **remote** Glassfish 4 instance, though:
Whenever I save nothing else happens in the logfiles and when I hit "Run", it runs the
Maven "war:war" goal and then deploys the .war to the remote server using "asadmin".

Does anybody know if that's a "documented" limitation or if I just do something wrong?
(JRebel would probably help, I know, but I hope to get it done without. Maybe it only works if NetBeans can directly write to a local $domain/autodeploy/ directory but that's only a guess)

My project uses the following NetBeans Project Properties:

- Build -> Compile -> Compile On Save: for both app and test
- Run -> Java EE Version: Java EE 6 Web
- Run -> Deploy On Save: checked

The pom.xml contains the following relevant plugin:

```
<profiles>
    <!-- References deployment settings in ~/.m2/settings.xml -->
    <profile>
        <id>devel-pom-build-profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>profile</name>
                <value>webmanager-bl-devel-settings-profile</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
....
</profiles>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
          ...
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <terse>false</terse>
                <echo>true</echo>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.glassfishDirectory}</glassfishDirectory>
                <user>${glassfish.user}</user>
                <adminPassword>${glassfish.adminPassword}</adminPassword>
                <domain>
                    <name>${glassfish.domain.name}</name>
                    <host>${glassfish.domain.host}</host>
                    <adminPort>${glassfish.domain.adminPort}</adminPort>
                </domain>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>  
                       <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                    </component>
                </components>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

All other questions I found here were either about the general way of deploying the app which I've done with the maven-glassfish-plugin or seem to refer to older versions of NetBeans which did not yet have the "deploy on save" feature in the Project Settings.
(But correct me if I missed one)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run glassfish in debug mode. I think that might provide the feature you are looking for.